# How to use variable in xpath in selenium webdriver using java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to use variable in xpath in selenium webdriver using java ??

Here is my lines of code:

```
for(int row =1; row<=20; row++) 
{   
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//*[text()=’PickReuest’]/table/tbody/tr[+row+]/td[2]”)).click(); 
}
```

But I am getting error as invalid xpath. Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: you have add the string in the middle

Comment: If you want help, you need to provide more information. We don't have the HTML or the page that you are looking at to determine if your XPath is valid.

Answer (score 2):

The xpath expression string should probably be

```
"//*[text()='PickReuest']/table/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td[2]"
```

also check if `PickReuest` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use String.format();

```
for(int row =1; row<=20; row++) 
{   
driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//*[text()='PickReuest']/table/tbody/tr[%s]/td[2]", row))).click(); 
}
```

This way is better if you store your x-path as a constants.

Answer (score 0):

```java
String newUser = "Cullen Sipes";
WebElement findthePatient = driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//div[@class='d-flex flex-column' and contains(text(),'" +newUser +"')]"
));
```

Trying to click on Cullen Sipes in a div class and it's a dynamic name